# How to plumb a drill press bit?

Tags: drill

I have a basic drill press.

I can plumb it with a square for one offs, but it's time consuming. Every time I change a bit I go back to make sure it is still perfectly vertical.

Is there a faster way to plumb it when I want to work quickly and switch bits for multiple projects?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it changes **every time you change a bit**, either your bits have damage, or your chuck does. Replace the suspect parts.

Drill bits you can sometimes just grind off projecting damage.

In some cases you can get new chuck jaws only, rather than a whole new chuck.

Then again, you appear to have a "fixture that attempts to make a portable hand drill act as a drill press" and it may not have the overall ability to hold adjustment that an actual drill press does. If the portable drill shifts within its clamps, then things will go out of plumb.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph - that is the key problem. The drill is not designed for this use so it is angled in the clamp. Replacing the bit inevitably loosens the drill and then it needs to be adjusted again. And now searching a bit (pun intended) - drill presses just at Home Depot alone range from $110 to more than $8,000!

Comment: Some of the better quality drill guides I've seen can easily be more than $100. Also, I've never seen a single-post design, so that might be some of the problem.

Comment: The better ones I've seen have their own chuck with a shaft the drill chuck drives (sometimes through a flexible coupling). That lets the drill be out of alignment without seriously affecting the drilling angle. Though old "real" drill presses can often be had cheap and occasionally free.